# Есть ли в Blender что-то типа режима Hidden Line?

Tags: blender

Есть ли в режимах `Viewport` Blender'а что-то типа max'овского `Hidden Line` - аналог `Wireframe`, но со скрытием невидимых (находящихся за другими полигонами) граней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В 2.8 есть такой режим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Включается выключением X-ray в режиме wireframe.

Answer (score 2):

У конкретного объекта можно включать отображение сетки на панели object:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это включает сетку, которую видно только спереди:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]